# Typescript errors on some imports

Tags: typescript

My toy project is a mono-repo that consists of several packages under the directory `packages`.  `packages` is organised as `TYPE`/`PACKAGE_NAME`, where `TYPE` refers to the package type; e.g. `libs`, `servers`.

There is a master `tsconfig.json` file in the project's root:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs"
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "baseUrl": "./packages",
    "rootDirs": [
      "./packages/libs",
      "./packages/etc"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./types"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "types",
    "packages/libs/libjest",
    "packages/*/*/run/*.ts",
    "packages/*/*/e2e",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

Each package in `packages/TYPE/PACKAGE_NAME` extends from the master configuration file:

```
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
}
```

I created a `global.d.ts` file and placed it in `packages/`.  It contains:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  export default any;
}

declare module "*.png" {
  export default any;
}
```

Whenever I run `../../../node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit` from one of the packages, I get errors such as the ones listed below:

```
../../libs/libicons/src/index.tsx:4:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../icons/Wiktionary.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import SvgWiktionary from "../icons/Wiktionary.svg";
```

Why is the compiler failing to pick up on the `"*.svg"` declaration in `global.d.ts` and erroring out?

Would greatly appreciate any pointers that help me solve this!